# Stick div inside container to end of the page view

Tags: html, css

In this case, the dynamic banner appears in some cases only. I have to put the Box div (angular component) at the end of the screen view but due to less height of its container, I am unable to do so. I tried setting the height to 100% which results in appearing the Box out of the screen. Just need a sample code for this layout so I can put it in my design. I have tried setting Box to `bottom: 0`, `position: absolute` but no luck.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make the Box parent a `flex` container and position it's children at the `flex-end`.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

See example below:

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 20px;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.box {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{ 
  padding:10px;
}

.div-wrapper{
  border:1px solid #000;
  padding: 20px;
}

.banner{
  min-height:100px;
  line-height:100px;
  background: crimson;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  border:2px solid green;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}

.content-wrapper{
  border:2px solid green;
  height:auto;
  display:flex;
  padding:20px;
  gap:20px;
}

.left-box,
.right-box{
  padding:20px;
  border:2px solid dodgerblue;
  width:50%;
}

.right-box{
  min-height:300px;
  position:relative;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:flex-end;
}

.right-box .box{
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  background: royalblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-wrapper">
  <div class="banner">
    BANNER
  </div>
  <div class="content-wrapper">
   <div class="left-box">
   </div>
   <div class="right-box">
      <div class="box">
      </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you add to this some information about your approach? How does this solve the problem at hand? What is the main point that future readers could learn from your answer? (If you can do that for all answers, so much the better).